# How would I change my computer to a specific locale?

Tags: powershell, language

I'm trying to change my windows 10 to iso-8859-1, or Western European for non-unicode programs. However, I can't find "Western European" on my computer in the locales in control panel, and changing it through powershell yeilds this error:

```
Get-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Set-WinSystemLocale'.
At line:2 char:1
+ PS C:\> Set-WinSystemLocale -SystemLocale iso-8859-1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand
```

Is there a way to do this properly? Maybe the problem is that I don't have the language downloaded...

Answer (score 2):

[Set-WinSystemLocale -SystemLocale](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0)
specifies a
[Culture names and identifiers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#CultureNames),
described as:

> The name is a combination of an ISO 639 two-letter lowercase culture code associated with a language and an ISO 3166 two-letter uppercase subculture code associated with a country or region.

Some other formats are available based on RFC 4646 and ISO 15924,
as explained in the documentation.

The codes "iso-8859-1" or "Western European" are not accepted here
(as you have found out already).
You need to supply a code as described in the documentation.